# getting big lag with scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate my menu with jquery - simply change padding depending on scroll. It works fine, however takes extremely long to execute (1-10 seconds). Any ideas? I have tried .on('scroll') but no change.

Both on Chrome and Firefox.

Fun thing - if I add alert(v); after 3rd line to be sure on scroll position, it animates well, without any lag ;x

```
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var v = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (v >= 150) {
                $('#header').animate({"padding": "15px 0px"},500);
            }
            else if (v < 150 ) {
                $('#header').animate({"padding": "50px 0x"},500);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

You can see the problem here:
http://monsiorski.com/_projects/robson/

Comment: scroll event is fired on each scrolled pixel (or with some padding but...). You are just here setting many many entries in queue animation.

Comment: @A.Wolff that should be an answer.

Comment: @catbadger An answer would be a fix to it, like debouncing the event or with some logic in handler to handle already animated element

Comment: Do you really need to animate the header *every time* the scroll happens? It seems like it should really only animate if the scroll *crosses* the `150` threshold.

Comment: @Santi yeah it should happen only when it crosses 150px. How should I change it?

Comment: @Congrim I was typing up an answer but it looks like silentw just posted one that performs exactly as I had mentioned.

Comment: Thanks anyways ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
    var isScrolled = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var v = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (v >= 150 && !isScrolled) {
            $('#header').animate({"padding": "15px 0px"},500);
            isScrolled = true;
        }
        else if (v < 150 && isScrolled) {
            $('#header').animate({"padding": "50px 0x"},500);
            isScrolled = false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'd probably include a simple line or two to explain why/how this fixes the issue, but a good answer in either case.

Comment: Use a flag to control whether it scrolled beyond `150px` or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of two reasons: A) The scroll event is fired *every scrolled pixel*, and B) you calculate a lot every time.

A) is fixed very easily, you can limit the amount of events fired by [dethrottling or debouncing](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) it. You can set it to fire every 20ms which is still extremely fast, but will save tremendous amounts of calls.

B) Limit the calculations you do. The more often you trigger a function, the more you have to doublecheck a function whether you can make it more lightweigth.

In your case you calculate how much is scrolled from the top, and *set the value every call*. Instead, you want to also store of you've already passed the threshold. If you've already passed it and the scrollvalue>threshold, there is no need to set it again to the same value. Same goes for scrolling back. *Checking a boolean is extremely fast.*

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me, it makes sense now!